# Cannot overwrite SASS !default variable?

Tags: javascript, sass, gulp, gulp-sass

I’m using Gulp’s gulp-ruby-sass to generate CSS files. I'm unable to overwrite variables in open-sans.scss. Here’s the code:

gulpfile.js

```
gulp.task('css', function () {
    return gulp.src(['app/assets/_variables.scss','app/assets/vendor/open-sans-fontface/open-sans.scss'])
        .pipe(sass())
        .on('error', function (err) { console.log(err.message); })
        .pipe(gulp.dest('public/css'));
});
```

app/assets/_variables.scss

```
$OpenSansPath: "/fonts";
```

app/assets/vendor/open-sans-fontface/sass/_variables.scss

```
@import "sass/variables";
@import "sass/mixins";
@import "sass/Light";
@import "sass/LightItalic";
@import "sass/Regular";
@import "sass/Italic";
@import "sass/Semibold";
@import "sass/SemiboldItalic";
@import "sass/Bold";
@import "sass/BoldItalic";
@import "sass/ExtraBold";
@import "sass/ExtraBoldItalic";
```

app/assets/vendor/open-sans-fontface/sass/_variables.scss

```
$OpenSansPath: "./fonts" !default;
$OpenSansVersion: "1.1.0" !default;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a main.scss file like this:

```
@import "app/assets/vendor/open-sans-fontface/open-sans.scss";
@import "app/assets/_variables.scss";
```

Then update the your files array to only include the main file:

```
gulp.task('css', function () {
    return gulp.src(['app/assets/main.scss'])
        .pipe(sass())
        .on('error', function (err) { console.log(err.message); })
        .pipe(gulp.dest('public/css'));
});
```

Comment: But why do you think the code that I posted above is not working? Is it because of syntax?

Comment: It's most likely how your html page is loading the css files being created. Using a `main.scss` like this is very common, and leaves you with just one `.css` file to deal with.